# How to remove [''] when i try to print a list

Tags: python

so far this is my code:

```
import random


choices = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]

computer = random.choices(choices)

player = input("Rock, paper or scissors??: ").lower()

print("Player :",player)
print("Computer: ",computer)"
```

when i try to print it says

```
Rock, paper or scissors??: gun
Player : gun
Computer:  ['Paper']
```

how can I remove `['']` from my output and only print "paper"

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `random.choice()` to select single random element. `random.choices()` returns list of k elements drawn with return: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp

Comment: No problem! If that helped remember to mark answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your print an array, thus call the first element. What was suggested in the comments above `random.choice()` is to select element in str format rather then array format

```
print("Computer: ",computer[0])
```

---

But if you want the parenthesis

```
print("Computer: [{}]".format(computer[0]))
```